# How to display records from multiple table adapter in a single crystal report?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, crystal-reports

I want to display records from multiple table adapter in a single crystal report.
I add two table adapter in my dataset and add this adapters to my crystal report with database expert.
There are two tabs named Data and Link in database expert. In Data ,I choosed my tableadapters and In link ,I determine relation of tableadapters .after that in link tab there are three button (ok,cancel,help) that i click ok and set my fields in columns of report.
I click ok and drag and drop my neccesary fields to the report.but when i ran my program crystal report is empty.
my dataset has two adapter(CustomerBill,PurchaseBill).i think there is a problem with my code behind:
DS_CustomerTransaction is my dataset and Crp_Cust_suratHesab is my crystal report

```
                    Dim cls As New Cls_Cust_Bill
                    Dim dt As New DataSet("DS_CustomerTransaction")
                    dt = cls.Search_Cust_Bill_RPT(ArrStr(0))
                    dt.Tables.Add("CustomerBill")
                    dt.Tables.Add("PurchaseBill")

                    Dim oRpt As New Crp_Cust_suratHesab()
                    oRpt.SetDataSource(dt)
                    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oRpt
                    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Your question needs serious formatting. What do you mean by table adapter? However have you linked the tables correctly? Can you check the sql query that the report creates and see if that is OK?

Comment: as you know,in dataset you can add tableadapter datatable and query .i add two table adapter that have different quey and can not union.but they have a same field named Customer_No that they linked by this field.